# Trim string in java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that writes an html file to a server. The string that is created contains unnecessary characters. I'd like to strip `WordMatch(content=` and `)` at the end of this string

```html
WordMatch(content=<div id='maincontentstyle'>
    <center>
        <div id='boxstyle'>
            <h3 id='title'>Title</h3>
                <center>
                    <div class='source'>
                        <div id='s1' class='draggyBox-small'>
                            k1
                        </div>
                        <div id='s2' class='draggyBox-small'>
                            k2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </center>
                    <table id='tablestyle'>
                        <tr>
                        <td id='row1'>
                            <div id='t1' class='ltarget'></div>
                        </td >
                        <td id='d1'>
                            d1
                            </td >
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td id='row2'>
                            <div id='t2' class='ltarget'></div>
                        </td >
                        <td id='d2'>
                            d2
                            </td >
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>)
```

before writing it to a file.

So far, I have created a web sever that process the raw html sent to the server. The program writes the html the file. I need help figuring out how to clean up the string.

Comment: [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: If you know the lengths of the parts you want to cut out, you can just take a substring that omits those parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String cleanedHTML = html.replace("WordMatch(content=","").replace(")","");
```